# Using Count and Sum at same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to create a query where I want to select employees from a table, count their number of certs from another table, a sum that total, and then display those that have more than 3 certs. I've tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        employee_bt.EMP_FNAME
        ," "
        ,employee_bt.EMP_LNAME
        ) AS "Full Name"
    ,count(earnedrating_bt.RTG_CODE) AS "Count of Rating"
FROM employee_bt
INNER JOIN earnedrating_bt ON earnedrating_bt.EMP_NUM = employee_bt.EMP_NUM
INNER JOIN rating_bt ON rating_bt.RTG_CODE = earnedrating_bt.RTG_CODE
GROUP BY employee_bt.EMP_NUM
    ,earnedrating_bt.RTG_CODE
ORDER BY employee_bt.EMP_LNAME ASC
```

But it returns something like this, I'd ideally want to just sum those employees up instead of it being 3 rows of 1 each I'd want 1 row where it just says 3.

```
Jeanine Duzak   1
Jeanine Duzak   1
Jeanine Duzak   1
John Lange      1
John Lange      1
John Lange      1
Rhonda Lewis    1
Rhonda Lewis    1
Rhonda Lewis    1
Rhonda Lewis    1
```

Should become:

```
Jeanine Duzak   3
John Lange      3
Rhonda Lewis    4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per employee name, then that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`:

```
group by employee_bt.EMP_NUM
```

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select concat(e.EMP_FNAME, ' ', e.EMP_LNAME) as Full_Name,
       count(*) as rating_count
from employee_bt e join
     earnedrating_bt er
     on er.EMP_NUM = e.EMP_NUM 
group by e.EMP_NUM
order by e.EMP_LNAME asc;
```

Notes:

- The `JOIN` to `rating` doesn't seem necessary for the count.
- Table references are assigned aliases.  This makes it easier to write and read queries.
- Name your columns so they do not need to be escaped.
- Use single quotes for strings.  Don't confuse strings with identifiers!
- The `GROUP BY` column is not consistent with the `SELECT` columns.  That is okay assuming that `EMP_NUM` is the primary key of the employees table -- a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `group by` clause:

```
group by employee_bt.EMP_NUM, earnedrating_bt.RTG_CODE
```

To:

```
group by employee_bt.EMP_NUM
```

This guarantees one row per `EMP_NUM`. For this to work properly, you need `EMP_NUM` to be the primary key of the `employee_bt` table. Otherwise, you need to add `emp_fname` and `emp_lname` to the `group by` clause.

You could also express this with a correlated subquery:

```
select concat(e.emp_fname, ' ', e.emp_lname) as full_name,
    (
        select count(*)
        from earnedrating_bt er
        inner join rating_bt r on r.rtg_code = er.rtg_code
        where er.emp_num = employee_bt.emp_num
    ) count_of_rating
from employee_bt e
order by e.emp_lname asc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to group by employee if you're noti interested in what the RTG code is, just the number.

Does this work?

```
select
concat(employee_bt.EMP_FNAME, " ",employee_bt.EMP_LNAME) as "Full Name",
count(earnedrating_bt.RTG_CODE) as "Count of Rating"


from employee_bt

inner join earnedrating_bt on earnedrating_bt.EMP_NUM=employee_bt.EMP_NUM
inner join rating_bt on rating_bt.RTG_CODE=earnedrating_bt.RTG_CODE


group by employee_bt.EMP_NUM
HAVING count(earnedrating_bt.RTG_CODE) >=3
order by employee_bt.EMP_LNAME asc
```